# I made a game in python using pygame. Is it possible to upload this game to google play or do I need to use kivy?

Tags: python, pygame, google-play-games

I created a game in python pygame which i intend on uploading to the google play store, I read that some people were having trouble getting pygame to work, do I have to convert the file or use kivy instead of pygame?

Comment: You can use a library called Pygame Subset For Android

Comment: Sadly, python is a very bad choice for game development, try using other languages like C, C++, C#, Java and such, as suggested, kivy is an option, tho it is not optimized for games, and personally, i dont like it.

Answer (score 0):

You should upload the apk version of the code because it is not easy to do with python. I think you should use kivy instead.

https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android